# Program Can't Find FilePaths

Tags: c#, file, xamarin

I am trying to develop an app and store data on JSON Files. The issue is that i try to find the file but get an error every time.
i simplified the code to debug faster but i still can't seem to find it

The App Main

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using TravelPack.Views;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace TravelPack
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
            Debug.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

            TravelPack.OOP.Lists.InitializeLists();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

the lists class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace TravelPack.OOP
{
    internal class Lists
    {
        private static List<Item> _items;
        private static List<Kit> _kits;
        private static List<TravelList> _travelLists;
        private static List<string> _weightUnits;
        private static List<string> _volumeUnits;
        private static List<string> _categories;

        public static void InitializeLists()
        {
            Lists._travelLists = new List<TravelList>();
            Lists._items = new List<Item>();
            Lists._kits = new List<Kit>();
            Lists._weightUnits = new List<string>();
            Lists._volumeUnits = new List<string>();
            Lists._categories = new List<string>();

            string filePath = @"D:\Documents\אישי\Projects\TravelPack\TravelPack\TravelPack\Data\BuiltInItems.JSON";
            string json =File.ReadAllText(filePath);//error occures here
            List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
            Lists._items.AddRange(items);
        }

        public static List<Item> GetItems() 
        {
            return Lists._items;
        }

        public static List<Kit> GetKits() 
        {
            return Lists._kits;
        }  

        public static List<TravelList> GetTravelLists() 
        {
            return Lists._travelLists; 
        }

        public static List<string> GetWeightUnits() 
        {
            return Lists._weightUnits; 
        }

        public static List<string> GetVolumeUnits()
        {
            return Lists._volumeUnits;
        }

        public static List<string> GetCategories()
        {
            return Lists._categories;
        }

        public static void Add(Item item) 
        {
            Lists._items.Add(item);
        }

        public static void Add(Kit kit)
        {
            Lists._kits.Add(kit);
        }

        public static void Add(TravelList list)
        {
            Lists._travelLists.Add(list);
        }

        public static void Add(string category)
        {
            Lists._categories.Add(category);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried moving the file to a shorter path, still got false on `File.Exists()`
I tried copying the full path but still got false.

The error is

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> Message=Could not find file "/D:\Documents\אישי\Projects\TravelPack\TravelPack\TravelPack\Data\BuiltInItems.JSON"

[image: Error Message]

Edit: The problem was that it is searching for data in the emulator and not the solution folders. That means I need to somehow move the data files to the emulator, figure out where it is stored in relation to the app and then use this path.

Comment: *"but get an error every time"* - What error do you get?  Which line produces that error?  *"but still got false"* - What specific file are you expecting to find and how have you confirmed that file exists?

Comment: @David I've edited the text so it'll focus only on the file that I want and not the test files. I also added where and what the error is.
but i'll write here aswell. the error is a runtime error in the line File.ReadAllText(filePath); in the lists class. system couldnt find the file. i am trying to access the json files i created

Comment: Your message looks like it has a slash before the D drive.

Comment: @LarsTech   True, now I noticed it. But since this / doesn't exist in the string, I don't know where it comes from (when i Debug.WriteLine(filePath), the / doesn't show)

Comment: Try making a simple path for testing: `c:\temp\data` and work from there.  Those characters after `document` might be causing the problem, or you have too many `TravelPack` folders than in reality.  Copy that folder path and test it in an explorer folder window.

Comment: I tried it by placing the document in d:\Documents and also in c:\ but both seem to fail with the same error

Comment: @LarsTech found the problem. added it to the main thread.
the reason it kept showing the "/" sign you noticed was because it was the emulators' path

Comment: @GaelPinto You should add that edit as an answer. (You can then accept your own answer after some time, I think it might be 48 hours.)

Comment: Are you debugging on an emulator or device?

Comment: @AliYousefi emulator. sorry for the late answer

Comment: @GaelPinto Emulator cannot find d:\ drive on windows, the direct path is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public static string ReadDataEmbeddedResource(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();//Gets the Assembly

            var resourceName = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Embedded_Data.{fileName}"; //name of file in the compiled assembly
            var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))// access to the content of the resource
            {
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Resource '{fileName}' not found in the assembly.");
                }


                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))//content of the resource
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error reading resource: {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
        public static string ReadJsonFile(string jsonFileName)
    {
        // Check if the file exists in writable location
        if (File.Exists(GetFilePath(jsonFileName)))
        {
            return File.ReadAllText(GetFilePath(jsonFileName));
        }

        // If not, copy from embedded resource
        var assembly = typeof(ResourceRead).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        // Debug.WriteLine($"{typeof(ResourceRead).Namespace}.{jsonFileName}");
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{typeof(ResourceRead).Namespace}.{jsonFileName}"))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            WriteJsonFile(jsonFileName, json); // Create the file in the writable location
            return json;
        }
    }

    public static void WriteJsonFile(string fileName, string json)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(GetFilePath(fileName), json);
    }
```

This code worked + making sure all files are "Embedded Resource"
The code is searching for the file, and creates a new file that can be accessed to and also changed (updating the file currently doesnt work because i havent worked on it yet).
with this code you can access the file and read its content